# How to escape single quotes into double quotes into single quotes

Tags: json, curl

Here is an example of command line that fit this description :

> ```
> curl  http://dumbdomain.com/solr/collection2/update/json -H
> 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' { "add": { "doc": { "uid":
> "79729", "text" : "I''ve got your number"} } }'
> ```

I already tried \' (not escaped), url encoded (not urldecoded at this other end!) and '' (quote disappear!), without success.

Comment: Use [`http`](http://github.com/jkbr/httpie), and don't use the title of the question to tag it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you replace ' by unicode encoded ' (which is \u0027), then it works:

```
curl http://dumbdomain.com/solr/collection2/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' { "add": { "doc": { "uid": "79729", "text" : "I\u0027ve got your number"} } }'
```

Strange, but worth to know!

Comment: Ah, so really you wanted to know how to escape an apostrophe?

Comment: Indeed. That's the title of this question: "How to escape single quotes (...)".

Answer (score 21):

An usual workaround in such cases is to put the data in a file and post.

```
$ cat post.json
{ "add": { "doc": { "uid": "79729", "text" : "I've got your number"} } }
```

And then invoke:

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @post.json http://dumbdomain.com/solr/collection2/update/json
```

This would obviate the need of escaping any quotes in the json.

Comment: Yeah, seen that in related posts, but I don't want to make it slower and more complex just to escape one char! There must be a way. BTW, I found something and I'm testing it.

Comment: awesome fix for instances where you need to do a lot of escaping.
i'm also looking into a quick little find and replace call to replace ' and " with their \u0022 and \u0027 counterparts

Answer (score 14):

In case you're using Windows (this problem typically doesn't occur on *nix), you can pipe the output from echo to curl to avoid the escaping altogether:

```
echo {"foo": "bar", "xyzzy": "fubar"} | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- localhost:4444/api/foo
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean how to get the JSON passed via the command line correctly?  If you're using Windows then you need to be careful how you escape your string.  It works if you use double quotes around the whole data string and then escape the double quotes for the JSON.  For example:

```
curl http://dumbdomain.com/solr/collection2/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d "{ \"add\": { \"doc\": { \"uid\": \"79729\", \"text\" : \"I've got your number\"} } }"
```

Comment: I've read round here that escaping with ^ on Windows should do the trick, but unfortunatly I'm batching this on CentOS.