# Tastypie deserialize results in {"error": ""}

Tags: json, django, rest, tastypie

I'm using tastypie with django. I have one line of code:

```
data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
```

I use this code from the command line to send a post request to my webserver:

```
curl -X post -d "{ 'username' : 'user', 'password' : 'password' }" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/login/ --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

When I run this, it results in a json response of

```
{"error": ""}
```

Looking at my server logs I see:

```
[15/Feb/2014 20:39:49] "post /api/user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 400 13
```

A log message logged immediately before the deserialize line will be logged successfully, but a log message logged immediately after the deserialize line will not be logged, so I am pretty sure the deserialize is wrong. Does anyone know what could be wrong or if I should consider something else as the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. Please check it [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). The 400 (bad request) status should give you clue about that. It should be: `{"username": "user", "password": "password"}`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612248/how-to-escape-single-quotes-into-double-quotes-into-single-quotes) you have some solutions how to escape `"` char in `CURL` command. Tastypie unfortunately raises exception without message here but we can easily fix that for future to save time for other people which will use your API.

```
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
class VerboseSerializer(Serializer):
    """
    Gives message when loading JSON fails.
    """
    # Tastypie>=0.9.6,<=0.11.0
    def from_json(self, content):
        """
        Override method of `Serializer.from_json`. Adds exception message when loading JSON fails.
        """
        try:
            return json.loads(content)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise BadRequest(u"Incorrect JSON format: Reason: \"{}\" (See www.json.org for more info.)".format(e.message))

class MyResource(BaseModelResource):
    class Meta:
        serializer = VerboseSerializer(formats=['json'])
```

Comment: i am facing this " name 'Serializer' is not defined " error . Thanks

Comment: the above issue it is fixed once i import 'Serializer' from 'tastypie.serializers' .