# CURL escape single quote

Tags: bash, shell, curl, elasticsearch

How can I make this work?

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9290/location/place' -d '{"geoloc": {"lat": "38.1899", "lon": "-76.5087"}, "longitude": "-76.5087", "admin_name1": "Maryland", "admin_name2": "St. Mary's", "admin_name3": "", "postal_code": "20692", "admin_code3": "", "country_code": "US", "admin_code1": "MD", "latitude": "38.1899", "admin_code2": "037", "accuracy": null, "place_name": "Valley Lee"}'
```

The `'` in `Mary's` is causing this to fail.  I am running it from a file like `cat curl-cmd.txt | sh` but it won't work from the command line either.  I've tried using `\'` and `\\'` and `\u0027` (the unicode `'`)

I'm stuck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612754/1745672

Comment: Right, as I said in my question, I've tried that.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I had the same problem. The simplest solution is to escape the apostrophe with a backslash in addition to wrapping it in a set of single quotes. `'\''`

For your use case, change `Mary's` to `Mary'\''s` and it should work.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9290/location/place' -d '{"geoloc": {"lat": "38.1899", "lon": "-76.5087"}, "longitude": "-76.5087", "admin_name1": "Maryland", "admin_name2": "St. Mary'\''s", "admin_name3": "", "postal_code": "20692", "admin_code3": "", "country_code": "US", "admin_code1": "MD", "latitude": "38.1899", "admin_code2": "037", "accuracy": null, "place_name": "Valley Lee"}'
```

> An alternate approach is to wrap the POST data (`-d`) in double quotes while escaping all nested occurrences of double quotes in the JSON string with a backslash.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9290/location/place' -d "{\"geoloc\": {\"lat\": \"38.1899\", \"lon\": \"-76.5087\"}, \"longitude\": \"-76.5087\", \"admin_name1\": \"Maryland\", \"admin_name2\": \"St. Mary's\", \"admin_name3\": \"\", \"postal_code\": \"20692\", \"admin_code3\": \"\", \"country_code\": \"US\", \"admin_code1\": \"MD\", \"latitude\": \"38.1899\", \"admin_code2\": \"037\", \"accuracy\": null, \"place_name\": \"Valley Lee\"}"
```

Comment: For some reason I needed your crazy solution for calling curl from PHP's shell_exec(), even though I'm using `--data-urlencode` Maybe has something to do with the way Linux processes the string before it gets to curl? Not sure.

Comment: First solution does not work on my Mac's console it produces the same effect as not escaping at all.

Comment: @PJBrunet - I presume it is the shell performing string concatenation on the command line. (e.g. `echo 'hello'\''world'` -> `hello'world`)

Comment: Can we Implement this in [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)?

Comment: @ASH – I am not sure if I understand the question; do you have a specific request in mind? This technique (i.e. shell string concatenation) should work for any `curl` request or command for that matter, not just this specific Elasticsearch request, as long as you are using a modern shell (e.g. bash, zsh, sh).

Comment: how can we parse single quote when is in a variable and that variable is the input for post

Comment: Great crazy solution. If you need this as a Java replacement, it gets even uglier: `s.replace("'", "'\\''");`

Comment: For me it didn't work if the first parameter (e.g. -XPOST) has single quote, but the second(e.g.  -d) has double quote. I had to change to double quote all parameters consistently

Answer (score 17):

**Rule Of Thumb**: *In case you want explicitly representing single quote or double quotes in your string on bash,* **Use backslash (`\`) depends on your String Wrapper** (should be in the same type). The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

**Examples**:

-**Double Quote Example** - `Use \"`

in case you want to print on bash `She said "Yes I Do"`

```
echo "She said \"Yes I Do\""
#output:
She said "Yes I Do"

echo 'she said "Yes I Do"' 
#output:
She said "Yes I Do"
```

-**Single Quote example** - `Use '\''`

in case you want to print on bash `My Daughter's dog likes cat treats`

```
echo "My Daughter's dog likes cat treats"
#output:
My Daughter's dog likes cat treats

echo 'My Daughter'\''s dog likes cat treats' 
#output:
My Daughter's dog likes cat treats
```

Comment: how do you explain the 3 quotes of '\'' and why \' doesn't work?

Comment: @pdem Don't look at them like 3 quotes. It's closing the previous quoted block then writing a single unquoted `\'` and then opening a new quoted block. The quoted blocks could be of different kind or one of them not exist eg: `"hello y"\''all'` or `'the car is his'\'` that would be interpreted as `hello y'all` and `the car is his'`