# Golang gin BindJSON omitting single quotes

Tags: json, go, post, go-gin

In GIN POST method, BindJSON omitting a single quote in the request body field
Here is my POST method

```
func TestPost(c *gin.Context) {
    var tmp struct{ Tmp string }
    c.BindJSON(&tmp)
    log.Printf("%+v\n", tmp)
    /* my work */
    c.Status(200)
}
```

Here is my CURL request

```
curl -X POST localhost:5005 --data '{"tmp":"example string 'GIN' have single quote"}'
```

In GIN Log

> 2020/04/15 11:35:39 {Tmp:example string GIN have single quote}
>
> [GIN] 2020/04/15 - 11:35:39 | 200 |      209.71µs |       127.0.0.1 | POST     "/"

As you can see in the logs, GIN does not have single quotes around it
My use case is to preserve the single quote that is passed as a payload

Please help !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122586/curl-escape-single-quote

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with CURL

```
curl -X POST localhost:5005 --data '{"tmp":"example string '\''GIN'\'' have single quote"}'
```