# How to handle escape characters in POST request in Java/JSON?

Tags: json, spring-boot, http, post, jackson

Controller :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/load"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
  public Response<Void> load(@RequestBody Request request) {
    try {
      service.load(request.getSqlStmt());
      return Response.success();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      LOGGER.info(ex);
      return Response.error(404, " Load Failed for : " + request.getSqlStmt());
    }
```

Java POJO :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Request implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @NotBlank private String sa;
  @NotBlank private String tableName;
  @NotBlank private String jobEnv;
  @NotBlank private String uowTo;
  @NotBlank private String sqlStmt;
  @NotBlank private String type;
}
```

A) Tried without escape quotes or characters first :-

```
curl -s -k --negotiate -u : -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"sqlStmt": "CALL CORE_LIB.SP_LOAD_STATUS_COMPLETE('2021-02-11',76,' ')", "uowTo": "20210815", "tableName": "tableName1", "jobEnv": "env1", "sa": "sa1", "type": "target"}' http://example.com:443/load
```

SQL statement changed from "CALL CORE_LIB.SP_LOAD_STATUS_COMPLETE('2021-02-11',76,' ')" to CALL CORE_LIB.SP_LOAD_STATUS_COMPLETE(2021-02-11,76,) instead of CALL CORE_LIB.SP_LOAD_STATUS_COMPLETE('2021-02-11',76,'')
The jdbc execute statement method call fails due to malformed string.

B) After adding escape characters :-

```
curl -s -k --negotiate -u : -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"sqlStmt": "CALL CORE_LIB.SP_LOAD_STATUS_COMPLETE(\\'2021-02-11\\',76,\\'\\')", "uowTo": "20210815", "tableName": "tableName1", "jobEnv": "env1", "sa": "sa1", "type": "target"}' http://example.com:443/load
```

Error :-

> 2021-08-17 18:17:51.823 ERROR 7 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3]
> .e.a.d.n.e.s.c.ControllerAdvice :
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Unrecognized character escape ‘,’ (code 44); nested
> exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Unrecognized character escape ‘,’ (code 44)  at [Source:
> (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 66] (through reference chain:
> c.e.a.d.n.e.s.m.Request[“sqlStmt”])
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Unrecognized character escape ‘,’ (code 44); nested
> exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Unrecognized character escape ‘,’ (code 44)  at [Source:
> (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 66] (through reference chain:
> c.e.a.d.n.e.s.m.Request[“sqlStmt”])
> at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:275)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:257)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:205)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
> [spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_242]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_242]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242] Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized
> character escape ‘,’ (code 44)  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);
> line: 1, column: 66] (through reference chain:
> c.e.a.d.n.e.s.m.Request[“sqlStmt”])
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1714)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:373)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3487)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]
> at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:269)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE] Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character
> escape ‘,’ (code 44)  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1,
> column: 66]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851)
> ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar!/:2.11.0]

Any pointers on how I can resolve the above issue currently facing?

Comment: This is a JSON problem not a Java one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CURL escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122586/curl-escape-single-quote)

Comment: Also you might want to google sql injection