# JSON data load containing single quote loses the single quote when sent through curl, how to escape/keep single quotes

Tags: json, scala, curl, cassandra, cql

I have this json data that I send to my system through curl and then query cassandra with it (parse to the where clause):

```
{"query": " name = 'Jane' "}
```

After receiving the data I need to extract the string value, namely `" name = 'Jane' "` but I always lose the single quotes inside. I tried escaping them with another single quote (as I've read in the datastax documentation), tried `\` and `\\` as escape symbols as well, neither worked. My language is Scala. Is there a way to salvage single quotes in JSON?

Comment: Based on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612248 you should be able to replace the single quotes with the Unicode encoded `\u0027`.

Comment: that worked fine. thank you.